# Trello api add attachment to a card wrong filename

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to add an attachment to a card using react-native and the Trello api.

I am using `react-native-image-picker` and I am getting a base64 from it.
when I try to add it to a formData like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", base64);
formData.append("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
formData.append("name", "test");

axios.post(url, formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    if (res && res.data) {
      console.log(res.data);
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    logError(error);
  });
```

I have this response from the Trello API:

```
{"bytes": 237852, "date": "2022-06-02T16:05:27.128Z", "edgeColor": null, "fileName": "Upload", "id": "62...", "idMember": "62...", "isUpload": true, "limits": {}, "mimeType": "image/jpeg", "name": "test@test.test", "pos": 16384, "previews": [], "url": "https://trello.com/1/cards/..."}
```

And the fileName is Upload and not Upload.jpg and when I download it from Trello I have all the byte written inside but as the file has no extension, my computer does not understand that this is an image and I think this is the same problem for the Trello attachment.

If someone can help me with this!